# GNU Parallel to replace piping xargs -n 1

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, xargs

I have a python script that operates on a list of state abbreviations as its single argument, and a text file that contains all the state abbreviation strings.

The normal call is...

```
$ mypy.py "AK"
```

...to run the script on Alaska.

I'm currently using the following to run the script on each state abbreviation taken from my statelist.txt file:

```
$ cat statelist.txt | xargs -n 1 ./mypy.py
```

I would now like to parallelize the execution, and GNU Parallels looks like the right option.  I saw [from here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__working_as_xargs__n1__argument_appending) that this should be the syntax for replacing `xargs -n1`:

```
$ find . -name '*.html' | parallel gzip --best
```

So, my attempts were

```
$ cat statelist.txt | parallel python mypy.py
```

and

```
$ cat statelist.txt | parallel python mypy.py {}
```

But both of these are returning:

```
/bin/bash: mypy.py: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'AK' is not defined
```

It seems to be passing it in unquoted perhaps?  But when I add quotes to the '{}' it passes in a literal "{}".

Comment: the first call looks good, actually. but `/bin/bash: mypy.py: command not found` looks more like you're in a wrong cwd of something unrelated. can you try to put in the absolute path to mypy.py?

Comment: Try `cat statelist.txt | parallel python ./mypy.py`

Comment: same, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'AK' is not defined`  this is super weird because the other command works totally fine in exactly the same terminal immediately before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cat statelist.txt | parallel --gnu python mypy.py
```

Without `--gnu`, GNU parallel may choose to emulate an older tool by the same name (Tollef's parallel). `--tollef` is the default behavior on many distros, and is why your otherwise valid GNU style invocation fails.

PS: Chances are your `xargs` had a `-C` or `-P` for parallelization too.

Comment: Both worked, but thanks even more for the tip about -P in xargs.  That's what I ended up using to keep everything else familiar.

Comment: For future visitors: "So to lessen the frustration and the resulting support, --tollef was obsoleted [2013 FEB 22] and removed one year later." - https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#tollef